# how do I get all associated data for a given ID in CakePhp 3 using get()?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is my situation....

1. I can view item details based on item ID passed from GUI

   ```
   public function view($id = null){

   $id = $this->request->getData('assetsource_id');
   $assetSource = $this->AssetSources->get($id, [
       'contain' => ['Assets']
   ]);

   debug($assetSource);
   die();

   $this->set('assetSource', $assetSource);
   $this->set('_serialize', ['assetSource']);
   ```
2. When I debug, I get the following except...

   ```
   /src/Controller/AssetSourcesController.php (line 64)

     object(App\Model\Entity\AssetSource) {

     'id' => (int) 18,
     'name' => 'Donated',
     'created_by' => '',
     'assets' => [
   (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Asset) {

       'id' => (int) 1,
       'school_unit_id' => (int) 33,
       'asset_source_id' => (int) 18,
       'asset_description' => 'TOYOTA HILUX',
       'date_of_entry' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

           'time' => '2021-05-31T00:00:00+00:00',
           'timezone' => 'UTC',
           'fixedNowTime' => false

       },
       'date_of_purchase' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

           'time' => '2021-05-31T00:00:00+00:00',
           'timezone' => 'UTC',
           'fixedNowTime' => false

       },
       'grn_number' => 'KBHBBH92',
       'name_of_supplier' => 'TOYOTA ZAMBIA',
       'serial_number' => 'YTDIYTFYUFOGOOHH',
       'location' => 'BURSAR',
       'asset_category_id' => (int) 24,
       'asset_group_class_id' => (int) 65,
       'full_asset_number' => 'GGFUYG88',
       'condition_id' => (int) 12,
       'asset_status_id' => (int) 14,
       'value' => '400,000',
       'custodian_name' => 'JOE BANDA',
       'custodian_phone' => '0966010101',
       'custodian_email' => 'bursar@unza.zm',
       'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

           'time' => '2021-05-31T07:26:31+00:00',
           'timezone' => 'UTC',
           'fixedNowTime' => false

       },
       'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

           'time' => '2021-05-31T07:26:31+00:00',
           'timezone' => 'UTC',
           'fixedNowTime' => false

       },
       'created_by' => 'admin',
       '[new]' => false,
       '[accessible]' => [
           '*' => true,
           'id' => false
       ],
       '[dirty]' => [],
       '[original]' => [],
       '[virtual]' => [],
       '[errors]' => [],
       '[invalid]' => [],
       '[repository]' => 'Assets'

   }
      ],
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
      ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'AssetSources'
      }
   ```
3. Except when I pass the result to the view.ctp, `school_unit_id`, `asset_source_id`, `asset_category_id`, `asset_group_class_id`, `condition_id`, `asset_status_id` are showing the corresponding IDs as saved in Assets table.

   ```
                                   <?php foreach ($assetSource->assets as $assets) : ?>
                                       <tr>
                                           <td><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->school_unit_id) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->asset_description) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->date_of_purchase) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->name_of_supplier) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->location) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->condition_id) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->value) ?></td>
                                           <td><?= h($assets->custodian_name) ?></td>

                                       </tr>
                                   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```
4. How do I show the respective display fields instead of IDs? Notice `asset_sources` table is only associated to `assets` table. Then `assets` table is associated to `school_units`, `asset_sources`, `asset_categories`, `asset_group_classes`, `conditions`, `asset_status` tables. In my view. I want to see `school_unit_name` not `school_unit_id`. NOTE: I used bake commands to create the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on containment. It will let you include whatever you want. `'contain' => ['Assets' => ['SchoolUnits']]` should work here, and then you can use `$assets->school_unit->name` or something like that in your view.

Comment: Thank you @Greg. That worked like a charm. I will read on containment in the CakePhp cookbook. Again, thanks!!